# AWS API Gateway Post Request return 403 forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have a scenario where I need to use a login API to retrieve AWS access_key_id, secret_key, session_token, and ID token.

With that set of data i then need to sign the request before I can use a ruby http/net to call the post request to other API that requires AWS authentication

The issue is that the request managed to go through in Postman, but when do it on ruby, it fails.

I'm using this 
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3'

and the following code to retrieve the login, and it works

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'
require 'openssl'
require 'cgi'


uri = URI.parse("https://EXAMPLE.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/live/setup/cognito/login")
login_request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
login_request.content_type = "application/json"
login_request.body = JSON.dump({
  "username" => "USERNAME",
  "password" => "PASSWORD"
})

req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(login_request)
end


login_json_response = JSON.parse response.body
```

and then the following set to sign and call the POST request where it fails and returns 403 forbidden

```
signer = Aws::Sigv4::Signer.new(
  service: 'execute-api',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  access_key_id: login_json_response['access_key_id'],
  secret_access_key: login_json_response['secret_key'],
  session_token: login_json_response['session_token'],
  apply_checksum_header: false
)

signature = signer.sign_request(
  http_method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://EXAMPLE.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/live/orders/suppliers',
  headers: {
    'id_token' => login_json_response['id_token'],
    'content_type' => "application/json"
  }
)


require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

supplier_uri = URI.parse("https://EXAMPLE.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/live/orders/suppliers")
supplier_request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(supplier_uri)
supplier_request['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
supplier_request["Authorization"] = signature.headers['authorization']
supplier_request["X-Amz-Date"] = signature.headers['x-amz-date']
supplier_request["X-Amz-Security-Token"] =  signature.headers['x-amz-security-token']
supplier_request["id_token"] = login_json_response['id_token']

req_options = {
  use_ssl: supplier_uri.scheme == "https",
}

supplier_response = Net::HTTP.start(supplier_uri.hostname, supplier_uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(supplier_request)
end
```

The error message is "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."

Is there anything misconfigured above? Can anyone help me with this?

----- EDIT -----
Here i attach the exported curl request from Postman

```
curl -X POST \
 https://EXAMPLE.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/live/orders/suppliers \
  -H 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ASIAJB2MFOYYXX3E372Q/20180407/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;id_token;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=f8d7a7b493ab6e5f80205f334392ce2cacdb239e225cf0bc4e99fb9913e3c811' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: e15cbd1e-a02d-4943-842f-09cb36a2c6dc' \
  -H 'X-Amz-Date: 20180407T085649Z' \
  -H 'X-Amz-Security-Token: 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' \
  -H 'id_token: eyJraWQiOiJkQlVPdGIyWnJNN1Jab1lHR2FUdDZaS25pemJpYUk2XC9rXC80dHNBUDZwdXc9IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.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.VbWxzLgtqlFm4ralVVnrPa8kXV4iO-dvuQ7pM7LHGCUihPV_DtoeKzlhAgR3CSJpDUcJYE5ZHNd1CmT--0jgjZ9XO-lfwkQfByhpsbVCpWuOIZBYxC23Rvse-T4InisZmKiHTEmaJTcXg9gXLbwLBhH7kYl2tpLL3LHWHuUxlmk2VOTKzuXFzgXqEHO31wBtczVY2QLrUexRrJYJVcfBEb6u7ATVy3o8GwZD1AhpErZt94JFWj-k8yYxRCwSN8R4ZrBRkO4wfofXVSwLwW_jkr62dl9Fxsh2hFIiCT_R-zBWgZRLNoMW0jwFoqiwaWsdbxFuYYX5YvtkKmLh5JlgbA'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In postman, you can export the CURL command that is working.  Please post that here.

Comment: @Daiku Hi i have attached in the post, thanksss

Comment: You've inspected the results in `signature`, and compared them to what you've been using in Postman?

Comment: they are different, could it because of the X-AMZ-Date is different? how can we use get the exact same comparison?

Comment: I think you should add `id_token` header to the signed request. If I guess correctly, this header belongs to your application and not to AWS.